# Capturing old values for model in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I'm wanting to capture the old values within a model so I can compare with the new values after submission, and create audit logs of changes a user makes.

My guess is doing it with hidden input boxes with duplicated old value properties would be one way. But wondering if there are any other good alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just compare the object in the db with the submitted object before applying the changes?

Comment: I need to capture user id of the person updating the record, plus the code updates the whole record, rather than only the row being updated (think I binded the data incorrectly).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the save method, just go and get the original object from the database **before** saving the changes, then you have your old and new values to compare against? :)

Comment: Hmm.. sounds like a good idea! bit worried about performance hit of extra queries to database. also if update fails for what ever reason, it would have an audit entry for it.

Comment: Performance of extra queries? How many entries are you wanting to query? You could just query the database once by putting all the IDs in a collection, then selecting from the database where the ID is in that list of values, only 1 query for even 100 different items :)

Comment: @stats101: Don't optimize something you have no idea will create a bottleneck for you. That's just wasting time.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like standard auditing. You should not worry about what has changed just capture EVERYTHING and who made the change. Unless there is some sort of real time reporting that needs to be done.

**Possible auditing implementations:**

[CQRS](http://elegantcode.com/2009/11/11/cqrs-la-greg-young/), in a nutshell it tracks every change to a given object. The downside is it's an architecture that is more involved to implement.

The Rolling ledger. Each insert is a new row in the database. The most current row is used for display purposes, but with each update, a new row is inserted into the database.

Yet another approach is to save it off into an audit table.

All get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what mattytommo says is the preferred method all around

Instantiate new view model for creating a new entity

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id) {
    var entity = new Entity(id); // have a constructor in your entity that will populate itself and return the instance of what is in the db
    // map entity to ViewModel using whatever means you use
    var model = new YourViewModel();
    return View(model);
}
```

Post changes back

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(YourViewModel model) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        var entity = new YourEntity(model.ID); // re-get from db
       // make your comparison here
       if(model.LastUserID != entity.LastUserID // do whatever
       ... etc...
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also store the original model in the view bag and do something like this...

```
// In the controller
public ActionResult DoStuff()
{
    // get your model
    ViewBag.OriginalModel = YourModel;
    return View(YourModel);
}

// In the View
<input type="hidden" name="originalModel" value="@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.OriginalModel));" />

// In the controller's post...
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoStuff(YourModel yourModel, string originalModel)
{
    // yourModel will be the posted data.
    JavaScriptSerializer JSS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    YourModel origModel = JSS.Deserialize<YourModel>(originalModel);
}
```

I didn't get a chance to test this, just a theory :)